# Rails: Set creator of Entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, model, mongoid

Currently, I can add the creator_id like this in my controller:

```
@entry = Entry.new(params[:entry].merge(:creator => current_user._id))
```

If this is my model:

```
class Entry
  include Mongoid::Document

belongs_to :User

  field :creator, :type => String
  field :title, :type => String
  field :content, :type => String
  field :scorea, :type => Integer
  field :scoreb, :type => Integer
  field :scorec, :type => Integer
end
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model doesn't looks very good, do you really want to store the user_id in a string field?

I suggest you change your models to following:

```
class Entry
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :entries

  # field definitions
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :entries, :inverse_of => :creator
end
```

Once you change the models you can continue using what you are now or alternatively:

```
@entry = current_user.entries.build(params[:entry])
```

**Update:**

The method to initialize entry is not much different in the way I did it. It is just more towards the rails way of doing things. The main difference is that you were not using the associations. From your model definitions it is clear that you want a one-to-many association between user and entries and this is how you create such associations. Associations has a lot of goodies attached to them, like you can do following things:

```
user.entries << entry # add a entry to users, will automatically change entry.creator_id
entry.creator = user  # sets creato_id = user_id
entry.creator         # returns associated user. no need to do User.find(entry.creator_id)
user.entries          # returns all entries for use <=> Entry.where(creator_id: user.id)
```

for more details go to http://mongoid.org/docs/relations.html

Comment: This isn't working for me. Could you elaborate about why this is better?

Comment: I'm getting this error: `undefined local variable or method 'inverse_of' for User:Class`

Comment: you need to use `:inverse_of` and not `inverse_of`

Comment: Superb, @rubbish. Since I'm a rails noob, would you describe in your answer why this is better than my previous method?

Comment: Great. Rails/mongoid is new and exciting for a PHP/sql user. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are no better way to do. Or you can do it in 2 line :

```
@entry = Entry.new(params[:entry])
@entry.creator = current_user._id
```

this second case allow you to add `creator` field in `attr_protected`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this manner

```
   @entery = Entery.new(params[:entry])
   @entery.creator = current_user
   or
   @entery.creator_id = current_user.id 

hence you can assigned id of creator to this entery.
```